# cors problem using nuxt in with SSR and proxy

Tags: vue.js, cors, nuxt.js

I want to make a **simple wishlist** with **nuxt** (project for fun)
the idea is simple, the user add links to the main page for items he want ( ex: https://www.amazon.fr/Bracelet-ethnique-multicolore-pierres-aventurine/dp/B088FNK7WS?pd_rd_w=VcswS&pf_rd_p=93b57529-44d6-414c-8e38-22f57431b7bd&pf_rd_r=F71JXZXPJQFHJR7E6ZCB&pd_rd_r=5c6a3226-b724-44f0-9c7c-1f7d75b21c00&pd_rd_wg=AJYnZ ), links are stored to an array, ect...
for a better visual, i want to prefill the name of the item and display a picture of this item based on the **open graph** data of the link (if available), for this usage, i found this plugin: https://metascraper.js.org#/?id=usage (work fine) to scrape the metadata of the page i target.

**My problem is the following**:
when i do a simple `this.$axios.$get(link)` i have a cors issue (No** 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource**.) After some research, i found this error is due to **Server Side Rendering** and need to be solved with the usage of a **proxy**.
But the use of **@nuxt/proxy** need to define one **proxy** per website (ex: `'/amazon/': { target: 'https://amazon.com/', pathRewrite: { '^/amazon/': '' } }` )

*Or, i need to scrape data from any link my user put in her wishlist. Can i still use **@nuxt/proxy** or i need a more complex solution ?*

```js
// test function to scrape data

const metascraper = require('metascraper')([
    require('metascraper-description')(),
    require('metascraper-image')(),
    require('metascraper-title')()
  ])
async mounted() {
      const url = "https://website.com"
      const content = await this.$axios.$get(url)
      console.log(await metascraper({ html: content, url: 'https://website.com' }))
 }
```

EDIT:
Big thanks to **MAS**
i have make some tweaks to his solution to make it work with nuxt:

**meta-scraper.js**

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const url = require('url')
const metascraper = require('metascraper')([
  require('metascraper-description')(),
  require('metascraper-image')(),
  require('metascraper-title')()
])

export default async function(req, res, next) {
  // parse querydata from url (nuxt don't give req.query)
  let queryData = url.parse(req.url, true).query

  // retrieve data from axios
  const content = await axios.get(queryData.target)

  // scrape data from content data and url
  const result = await metascraper({ html: content.data, url: queryData.target })

  // stringify result end send it with res.end (nuxt don't provide res.send or res.json)
  await res.end(JSON.stringify(result))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is actually a browser security feature, and it's triggered when you try to access a resource from a different origin, read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

To work around it, simply fire the scraping request from the server-side, this way you can make your server act as a proxy. And since you are using nuxt you can easily achieve this through [server-middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/), thus you can create a custom API e.g:
*/api/meta-scraper?target=http://www.amazon.com...* and from there you can fetch the needed metadata. See the below example code.

***nuxt.config.js***

```
export default {
  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: '/api/meta-scraper', handler: '~/api/meta-scraper.js' }
  ]
}
```

***~/api/meta-scraper.js***

```
export default function (req, res, next) {
  // req is the Node.js http request object
  console.log(req)

  // res is the Node.js http response object
  // use metascraper here to scrape metadata

 const content = await axios.get(req.params.target)
 const result = await metascraper({ html: content, url: req.params.target })
 
 return res.send(result);
}
```

***~/some-page.vue***

```
async asyncData({ $axios }) {
  try {
    const result = await $axios.$get('/api/meta-scraper', {
      params: {
        target: 'https://amazon.com'
      }
    });
    console.log(result); // scraped meta
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
},
```

Hope I have helped!